# Who is the subject in 思うがままの人生を送れたら、どんなに幸せだろう?

Tags: meaning

> 思うがままの人生を送れたら、どんなに幸せだろう。

If X can send man as what Y imagine, how happy it will be.

Do you know the subject X and Y in the sentence above?

Comment: We definitely need context to be able to tell here, so maybe you could give us some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 思うがままの人生【じんせい】を送れたら、どんなに幸せだろう。
>   How happy I will be if I could live a life as I wish.

The omitted subject should be "I" throughout the sentence. 人生 is "(human) life", and [人生を送る](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E4%BA%BA%E7%94%9F%E3%82%92%E9%80%81%E3%82%8B&ref=sa) is a very common set phrase that means "to live a life". The sentence does not say 人を送る ("to send a person").

One of the meanings of 送る is "to spend (time)", "to live."

> - 楽しい学校生活を送る
> - 希望に溢れた日々を送る